# Need to redirect dynamic subdomain to new main domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

Currently I have a domain with the format of `subdomain.domain.com/path`, where `subdomain` is a variable. I want to redirect all of the possible subdomains to `subdomain.new_domain.com/path` so that if someone goes to `subdomain_A.domain.com` or `subdomain_B.domain.com` they get redirected to `subdomain_A.new_domain.com` and `subdomain_B.new_domain.com` respectively.

So far I have tried

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([.*]).domain.com$
RewriteRule (.*) %1.new_domain.com/$1
```

to accomplish this but for some reason the regexes will not substitute in the way that I am hoping for.

Can anyone please offer some suggestions or even confirm that this is possible using apache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is not entirely correct. You can use this redirect rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www\.)([^.]+)\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^ http://%1.new_domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```